# Why does a noncyclic group of order $6$ have at least $1$ element of order $3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I approached this question by trying a proof by contradiction. Consider a group $G$, which has $\{ e, a, b, c, d, f\}$ where all elements other than $e$ have order $2$.

I am not sure how to proceed forward with just this information in order to achieve a contradiction.

Any information would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: There are only two groups of order $6$. The noncyclic one is $S_3$.

Comment: Yea, but how does one prove that it indeed has 1 element of order 3.

Comment: There are lots of proofs of this of varying degrees of complexity and requiring various preliminaries. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: So having {e, a, b, c, d, f}, I could say ab = ba = c, ac = ca = b, bc = cb = a, but then I dont know what ad might be, or af, etc.

Comment: Even if it is cyclic it has to have at least one element of order $3$.

Comment: You can turn $G$ into a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and reach a contradiction, since there is no group with six elements such that each non-identity element has order two

Comment: Compare also with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570225/why-group-of-order-6-has-to-have-just-two-elements-of-order-3) and other similar ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Groups of order 6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742975/groups-of-order-6), or alternatively https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570225/why-group-of-order-6-has-to-have-just-two-elements-of-order-3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $G$ does **not** contain any elements of order 6 nor any elements of order 3.

Since the only possible orders for non-identity elements are 2, 3 and 6, we must have
$h^2=e$ for any $h ∈ G$.

However, this makes $G$ an abelian group.

Pick two distinct non-identity elements of $G$, say $h_1$ and $h_2$. They must each have order 2.

From here, you can check that $\{e, h_1, h_2, h_1h_2\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order 4,

implying $4|6$ by Lagrange's theorem, which is a contradiction.

Thus, $G$ **does** have an element of order 3.

Also, note that if $G$ has an element $g$ of order 6, then $[g]$ does contain an element of order 3, namely $g^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The only groups of order 6 up to isomorphism are $S_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. In $S_3$ the element $(123)$ is an element of order $3$ and $[2]$ is an element of order $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. So as lulu mentioned this is true regardless of if your group is cyclic or not.

**Edit:** If you want a contradiction, suppose $G$ is a group of order $6$ which isn't cyclic and that every element other than the identity has order $2$. Note this implies your group is abelian. This will give a contradiction via Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: I would imagine the OP is trying to show that there are only two groups of order three by proving this statement

Answer (score 1):

You can answer this using some higher-level yet handy theorems.

> **Theorem (Cauchy's Theorem):** Let $G$ be a group of order $n$. Suppose $p$ is prime such that $p\mid n$ (*i.e.*, $p$ divides $n$). Then there exists a $g\in G$ such that $|g|=p$.

(For a proof, see the **Corollary** of **Theorem 24.3** of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.)

> **Theorem:** Let $p$ be prime. Consider a group $G$ with $|G|=2p$. Then $G\cong \Bbb Z_{2p}$ or $G\cong D_p$, the dihedral group of order $2p$.

(For a proof, see **Theorem 7.3** of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.)

---

Since $6=2\times 3$, your group $G$ has an element of order $3$ by Cauchy's Theorem. Since $G$ is not cyclic, $G$ must be isomorphic to $D_3$.

---

> **Bonus Theorem:** The groups $D_3$ and $S_3$ are isomorphic.

(For a proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/932843/104041).)